# Resonance frequency with python curve-fit, error maxfev reached

Tags: python

I have measured a voltage over a LCR tank circuit (with unknown components) to determine the resonance frequency. Ik have performed a broad frequency sweep and measured the voltages. Now I want to determine the exact location of the resonance peak by adding a fit to the data. The [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTpFe.png) looks like a damped, driven, harmonic oscillator so I used the following function to fit the data to: A = F0 / sqrt((k-mw^2)^2 + (bw)^2).

This is the code I have for now, but I get the following error: "Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 5000."

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit( f, F0 , k, m, b):
    w = 2 * np.pi * f 
    return F0 / np.sqrt( ( k - m*w**2)**2 + ( b * w )**2 )

fuData = np.loadtxt( "ohlVW.txt", delimiter=',' )
fuData = fuData[ fuData[:,0].argsort()]

f = fuData[:,0]
U = fuData[:,1]

popt, _ = curve_fit(fit, f, U, maxfev=5000)

F0, k, m, b = popt
print(popt)

plt.scatter(f, U)

x_line = np.arange(min(f), max(f), 1)

y_line = fit(x_line, F0, k, m, b)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(f, U)
plt.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')
plt.show()
```

Increasing maxfev did not work. How can I adjust the code to get a nice fit over the data?

Comment: Start by trying with appropriate estimated starting values for your fit parameters. You don't seem to set any, so they will all be set to 1, which may be way too far off for some parameters for the algorithm to find a good fit.

Comment: Alternatively, and generally better for non-linear fitting: normalize your data and fitting parameters. The former means making sure your data is of order 1-ish; in your particular case, the `y` values are probably fine, the frequencies should probably be converted to KHz or MHz. For the parameters, check that with `y` of order 1 and `x` of order 1, the various parameters `F0`, `k`, `m` and `b` are also of order 1.